# Gradle doesn't build project: Argument list too long (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle doesn't build my android project.

Gradle version: 1.12 
Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.3 x86_64

**--stacktrace**

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Argument list too long
    at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.hash.DefaultHasher.hash(DefaultHasher.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$1.run(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.OutputFilesStateChangeRule.create(OutputFilesStateChangeRule.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Argument list too long
    at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:47)
    ... 62 more

BUILD FAILED
```

**--debug**

```
./gradlew build --debug
 ...
  Determining if task ':app:packageDebug' is up-to-date
    16:01:04.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:packageDebug'
    16:01:04.489 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:packageDebug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.073 secs.
    16:01:04.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 2.373 secs, idle: 0.019 secs
    16:01:04.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    16:01:04.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    16:01:04.494 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    16:01:04.494 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    16:01:04.494 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] java.io.IOException: Argument list too long
    16:01:04.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Argument list too long
    16:01:04.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    16:01:04.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
    16:01:04.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Argument list too long
    16:01:04.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:57)
    16:01:04.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:34)
    16:01:04.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.hash.DefaultHasher.hash(DefaultHasher.java:24)
    16:01:04.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:51)
    16:01:04.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:28)
    16:01:04.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$1.run(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:53)
    16:01:04.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    16:01:04.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    16:01:04.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    16:01:04.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    16:01:04.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:193)
    16:01:04.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:58)
    16:01:04.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:49)
    16:01:04.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.java:89)
    16:01:04.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter.java:43)
    16:01:04.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.OutputFilesStateChangeRule.create(OutputFilesStateChangeRule.java:34)
    16:01:04.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:45)
    16:01:04.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:126)
    16:01:04.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:69)
    16:01:04.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    16:01:04.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    16:01:04.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    16:01:04.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    16:01:04.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    16:01:04.506 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    16:01:04.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    16:01:04.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    16:01:04.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    16:01:04.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    16:01:04.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    16:01:04.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    16:01:04.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    16:01:04.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    16:01:04.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    16:01:04.509 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    16:01:04.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    16:01:04.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    16:01:04.510 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    16:01:04.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    16:01:04.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    16:01:04.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    16:01:04.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    16:01:04.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    16:01:04.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    16:01:04.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    16:01:04.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    16:01:04.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    16:01:04.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    16:01:04.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    16:01:04.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    16:01:04.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    16:01:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    16:01:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    16:01:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    16:01:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    16:01:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    16:01:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    16:01:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    16:01:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    16:01:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    16:01:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    16:01:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    16:01:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
    16:01:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Argument list too long
    16:01:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:47)
    16:01:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 62 more
    16:01:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    16:01:04.519 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
    16:01:04.520 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
    16:01:04.520 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
    16:01:04.520 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 7.203 secs
    16:01:04.522 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
    16:01:04.522 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
    16:01:04.524 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.6/module-metadata.bin)
    16:01:04.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.6/artifact-at-repository.bin)
    16:01:04.526 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/modules-2).
    16:01:04.527 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/settings.gradle' (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/settings_434o119u0k3mm6r0riat1uocnh/SettingsScript/buildscript).
    16:01:04.527 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on no_buildscript class cache for settings file '/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/settings.gradle' (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/settings_434o119u0k3mm6r0riat1uocnh/SettingsScript/no_buildscript).
    16:01:04.527 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for build file '/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/build.gradle' (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/build_3vlps59vafaf2u0q63a0kfufmh/ProjectScript/buildscript).
    16:01:04.528 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file '/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/build.gradle' (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/build_3vlps59vafaf2u0q63a0kfufmh/ProjectScript/no_buildscript).
    16:01:04.528 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for build file '/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/app/build.gradle' (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/build_1b2srmfc014qjbp9qi1gmue3j2/ProjectScript/buildscript).
    16:01:04.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file '/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/app/build.gradle' (/Users/shandrakovag/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/build_1b2srmfc014qjbp9qi1gmue3j2/ProjectScript/no_buildscript).
    16:01:04.540 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/.gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin)
    16:01:04.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/.gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin)
    16:01:04.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache outputFileStates.bin (/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/.gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin)
    16:01:04.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/.gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin)
    16:01:04.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (/Volumes/STORAGE/projects/PaintKiller2/.gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts).
    16:01:04.544 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryDependencyMetadataCache] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 13, cache instances: 3, modules served from cache: 0, artifacts: 0
    16:01:04.545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 2 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.001 secs)
    16:01:04.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolved configuration cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
    16:01:04.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
```

Comment: Can we see your build files?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "paintkiller.qulix.com.paintkiller"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

Comment: I resolved my problem. After clearing my project gradle can build it. It repeats sometimes and always solved by cleaning project.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation gradle started build project after cleaning (Android Studio/Build/Clean Project).

Comment: Same here, however the problem repeats regularly. Is there some long term solution? Or is this gradle / android studio bug?

Comment: It's gradle/android studio bug.

Comment: I believe its a macos issue instead, I haven't seen it happening in other OS.